# Can a WCF SOAP service consume an external REST API?

Tags: c#, rest, web-services, wcf, soap

I need to authenticate APP "A" according to APP "B" authorizations, using an existent and available login method. Just checking username and password, no token, no certificate. Basic auth.

I do not control any of that app, so I manage to create a web service to intermediate communications.

I am quite new to this, so I have starting reading about it. I have ended up some simple examples using WCF to perform it. I'm using c#.

Should I do it using WCF? What should be (conceptually) my approach?

[image]

Comment: Be sure to encrypt that password.

Answer (score -1):

You can do anything you want from a WCF service, as long as you keep the constraints of running as a Windows Service (either directly or through IIS) in mind.

So yes, you can just use HttpClient or RestSharp to talk to the REST API from your WCF code.